# Training with unclean data

Tags: machine-learning, data-preprocessing

I am working on a supervised machine learning problem (text classification). My data consists of labels that were assigned by an automated system and, in theory cleaned by humans when needed.

After manually checking 1000 randomly selected training points (out of 15000 points), I noticed that around 80% of the points are correct.

My plan is to use the portion of the data I corrected as a test set. However, I am wondering whether my training data is clean enough. I do not have resources to clean the whole data-set.

Comment: Then train a machine to do it using the subsample you have cleaned :)

Comment: That is a fairly small sample given that I have around 50 classes.